# NSObject Class initialisation

Tags: objective-c, class, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

Assume I have two `UIViewController`s and a Settings (`NSObject` Class). And I need in both controllers some information contained in the Settings Class.

I alloc and init the Settings Class in the first controller, how can I use the same instance of the class in the second controller without allocating it again?

I know I can send the info from one controller to the other, or any other techniques, but is there a way I avoid allocing a class multiple times ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You do not initialize a class or a class object, but instance objects of a class.

You do not have to create new instance every time you publish information to somebody, including view controllers. Simply give both view controllers a property `settings`and set the property after creation of the view controller with always the same instance of `Settings`.